# Why does using CSS3 transition in Cordova/Phonegap Webkit browser result in a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, memory-leaks, css-transitions

I have a Cordova 3.3.1 app running on Android 4.0.4 which displays images in a loop at 15 second intervals. I've currently implemented a crossfade solution as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/chaddjohnson/ka9cqdnt/16/. This solution relies on two images layered in the same position, and the opacity of the top image changes from 0 to 100 (and vice versa) with each 15-second interval. This is the only page in the app.

Strangely I have found that if I include a CSS transition, the Cordova app will cause the device's memory to decrease over the course of an hour, and eventually the app will crash. Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.ad-image:last-child {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I'm absolutely sure this is causing the problem, as when I simply remove just these lines of CSS, the app works fine with no memory leak. And when I add the lines back, the memory leak comes back -- repeatably.

Does anyone have any ideas why this memory leak is happening? Is it a Webkit bug? Or maybe something related to my implementation (please see the jsfiddle)?

Comment: Not a proper solution, but you could lose the browser prefix and only use `transition`. Also, have you seen [will-change](http://caniuse.com/#feat=will-change)?

Comment: Is it rendering in the background the whole time the app runs and no matter on which page you are? I have an app with many transitions on about 8 - 10 pages and no memory issues.

Comment: @Sithys There is only one page in this app -- the one that shows the images. No other pages, and no navigation. So yes, the img src attributes are constantly changing every 15 seconds.

Comment: @Ciprian Unfortunately -webkit-transition is necessary in the Cordova Webkit browser, and transition does nothing.

Comment: @Ciprian Also, using will-change did not help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

well i my self encountered this problem a lot. as the matter of fact i decided to disable every kind of effect. especially effects between pages. i think the problem rise from web-view. if you use android native code android will manage the memory and this sort of problems won't happen often. of course there are things that u can do such as disabling hardware acceleration but trust me it's still not good as what you want. my advise is to avoid any unnecessary effect as possible.

Comment: I actually only have one page in this app which is fully powered via JavaScript and CSS. How can I use native Android code to handle transitions of images displayed on pages?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the `:last-child` property and assign a class (temporary) to your last element? Just to isolate the problem.

Is it the `:last-child` selector or is it the transition causing the memory leak?

Also, can you add `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to your selector in order to activate hardware acceleration?

> Native applications can access the device’s graphical processing unit
>   (GPU) to make pixels fly. Web applications, on the other hand, run in
>   the context of the browser, which lets the software do most (if not
>   all) of the rendering, resulting in less horsepower for transitions.
>   But the Web has been catching up, and most browser vendors now provide
>   graphical hardware acceleration by means of particular CSS rules.

Also, if it still doesn't work, try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your selector.

Comment: Unfortunately none of this helped :(